# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter

Tags: java, android-studio, slf4j

When I try to add the google map dependency

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0+'`
 in android, I'm getting following error..

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(Unknown Source)..
```

I am using `slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar` for some functionality...i want to keep both lib.

Comment: this error is related to **SLF4J** library. keep updated valid jar file for SLF4J

Comment: i have used valid jar only, when i remove google map dependency it works fine...

Comment: You and play-services-maps use a different version of slf4j. The simplest way to fix this is to use the exact of same version of slf4j as play-services does.

Comment: there is no same version of lib for both

Comment: Try to remove the dependency to SLF4J, gradle will use the one imported by play-services-map.